# Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value in redis when pushing data on a list

Tags: c#, azure, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

Created redis list and setting key like following getting me error

```
      public async Task MyMethod<T>()
                {
//if i'm doing following it is working
  string listname = "listname";
                    string listkey = "key";
                    RedisList<string> demodemo = new RedisList<string>(Settings, listname);
                    await demodemo.LeftPush(listkey);

//but i want to do it like below it is thoughing exception
            RedisList<string> list = new RedisList<string>(Settings, typeof(T).Name.ToString());
    string mykey = "myId";
    await list.LeftPush(mykey);
```

> getting following error :
>
> Result Message:   StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException : ERR
>   Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a side note; `RedisList<T>` is not a SE.Redis type, so I can't comment on that directly. However: that error message comes from redis-server itself when you try to do things that don't make sense; for example, if `foo` is a *string*, you can't `lpop foo` or `zcard foo`.

So the question becomes: *what is the value that is stored?* I can't answer that for you, but: the server can. If you are familiar with redis-cli, then `debug object foo` or `object encoding foo` might be useful. Although to be honest, you'll probably do just as well by guessing:

- `strlen foo` - if this works, it is a string
- `hlen foo` - if this works, it is a hash
- `llen foo` - if this works, it is a list
- `scard foo` - if this works, it is a set
- `zcard foo` - if this works, it is a sorted-set

Note that all of these commands are available via SE.Redis, but for investigating a suspect database, redis-cli is usually easier.

What has probably happened is you've accidentally reused a key name without realizing it. Which is perhaps a great advertisement for the value of adding a prefix to your key names - something else that SE.Redis can do for you automatically when talking to a database.

Comment: I'm using SE.Redis but using it thorough `https://github.com/neuecc/CloudStructures` typeof(T).Name.ToString() is nothing but class name like `Customer` but I wonder why i can not use it? please guide.. as you said here foo is my `typeof(T).Name.ToString()` this?

Comment: @Neo you absolutely can use `typeof(T).Name` (the `.ToString()` is redundant); that isn't the problem. The problem is that *something else is already called `Customer` in your database*. So: what is `Customer` currently, and why are you trying to use the same key twice for different purposes? Note: `typeof(T).FullName` might have less conflicts, as might `"/arbitrary-prefix/" + typeof(T).Name`